# Remove issues from Issue Navigator in Xcode 4?

Tags: debugging, xcode4

Having some trouble with Xcode 4 here. Sometimes I hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> (Launch Tests) instead of <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> (Build and Run) and it's frustrating for a perfectionist like me when error "Unit tests are not implemented yet in XXXXXtests" remains in  the Issue Navigator even after a successful Build & Run.

The question, in a nutshell, is how do I remove or ignore individual issues in the Issue Navigator in Xcode 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click on your project in the project navigator, in your Project View you should now have a left view with

**Project**

*your project name*

**Targets**

*your target name*

*your target name tests*

you know, where u have all the build settings and stuff

right click on the tests one and delete it